# How to get R shiny font rendering right on Linux?

Tags: r, linux, shiny

I copied the "Table of fonts" example from http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Fonts/ into a minimal shiny application. I run the shiny code on a Linux Debian server. Unlike in the example, fonts don't appear to change at all, and the default font does not look good.

[image]

If I run the same code on my Ubuntu machine, I get a similar result, except that "plain" variant is thicker and looks better.

If I run the same code *outside shiny*, the font changing works as in the Cookbook example both in Debian and in Ubuntu.

I can make the shiny variant work by using

```
library(Cairo)
options(shiny.usecairo=FALSE)
```

However, then I have a different problem: the fonts without Cairo look thinner/blurier than with it (I am not entirely sure, but one reason could be I am embedding plots inside `uiOutput` widgets).

What is the way to get font rendering in png graphics right on Linux servers? Am I missing some system packages? How can I debug this? How can I change the default shiny plots font?

Here is the code:

```
#library(Cairo)
library(shiny)

#options(shiny.usecairo=FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(mainPanel(plotOutput("plot")))

server <- function(input,output){

  output$plot<-renderPlot({

fonttable <- read.table(header=TRUE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                        text='
Short,Canonical
mono,Courier
sans,Helvetica
serif,Times
,AvantGarde
,Bookman
,Helvetica-Narrow
,NewCenturySchoolbook
,Palatino
,URWGothic
,URWBookman
,NimbusMon
URWHelvetica,NimbusSan
,NimbusSanCond
,CenturySch
,URWPalladio
URWTimes,NimbusRom
')

fonttable$pos <- 1:nrow(fonttable)

library(reshape2)
fonttable <- melt(fonttable, id.vars="pos", measure.vars=c("Short","Canonical"),
                  variable.name="NameType", value.name="Font")

# Make a table of faces. Make sure factors are ordered correctly
facetable <- data.frame(Face = factor(c("plain","bold","italic","bold.italic"),
                                      levels = c("plain","bold","italic","bold.italic")))

fullfonts <- merge(fonttable, facetable)


library(ggplot2)
pf <- ggplot(fullfonts, aes(x=NameType, y=pos)) + 
             geom_text(aes(label=Font, family=Font, fontface=Face)) +
             facet_wrap(~ Face, ncol=2)
    pf  
   })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Edit:** With a bit of more search I found this function [described here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgJnz.png) that allows me to change the default font:

```
CairoFonts(
    regular="FreeSans:style=Medium",
    bold="FreeSans:style=Bold",
    italic="FreeSans:style=Oblique",
    bolditalic="FreeSans:style=BoldOblique"
)
```

The example works in both Ubuntu and Debian. However, in a slightly more complicated app that puts plots inside an uiOutput, the Debian server seems to ignore my CairoFonts setting.

Comment: As noted in the cookbook: `Notice that on the system that generated this picture, most of the fonts (at the top) don’t really work. Only the basic fonts (at the bottom) work.` So, this is answered mostly by `how install fonts on debian`