# Lato font doesn't work in ggplot2 graph in Shiny on Linux server

Tags: r, linux, ggplot2, shiny

I'm building an interactive data visualization in Shiny that will live on a Linux server. When I run app.R on Windows and Mac OSX, Lato works perfectly in renderplot() AND all other text (titlePanel(), selectInput, etc.).

When I run app.R on the server, Lato works perfectly everywhere EXCEPT for the ggplot2 plot.

Server

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(extrafont)
library(grid)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(scales)

quartz.options(width = 8.3, height = 5.5, dpi = 72)

ui <- fluidPage(

  theme = "shiny.css",

  plotOutput("chart")
)
```

UI

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$chart <- renderPlot({

  diamonds %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = carat, y = price)) +
    geom_point() +
    labs(title = "Gg Lato") +
    theme(text = element_text(family = "Lato"))

  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato');

* {
  font-family: Lato;
}
```

I tried `options(shiny.usecairo=FALSE)` but it did not work.

I also saw this [recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42347968/how-to-get-r-shiny-font-rendering-right-on-linux). I think I'm having a different problem since `options(shiny.usecairo=FALSE)` won't even change the fonts.

Thank you for your time. I'm at a total loss for what to try next.

Comment: you need to use the extrafont package and install Lato on the server with it and also install Lato *ttf* fonts on the server as well as the R part.

Comment: np. fonts and R (or python for that matter) are bad enough. throw linux into the mix and it's crazy town.

Comment: Do you mind explaining why this helps? I'm already loading extrafont and the fonts must be installed since they are working elsewhere?

Comment: the fonts must not be installed on the linux box. the CSS import makes the web ones work fine but not the PNGs that ggplot2 makes. if you're generating SVGs from ggplot is it with the svg device or svglite device. the latter shld work with webfonts.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you, that really helps me understand your suggestion.